# Cs cart product queries very slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, multithreading

I have some problems with my CS-Cart 4.2.
I've got around 700k filters and 180k products.
Sometimes, it takes around 170 seconds for query to complete.

```
d    | User             | Host      | db          | Command | Time | State                        | Info                                                                                                 | Progress |
+-------+------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 659   | root             | localhost |             | Sleep   | 207  |                              |                                                                                                      | 0.000    |
| 13462 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 2    | Waiting for table level lock | REPLACE INTO cscart_product_features_values (`product_id`, `lang_code`, `feature_id`, `variant_id`)  | 0.000    |
| 13466 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Sleep   | 2    |                              |                                                                                                      | 0.000    |
| 13950 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 1    | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT v.feature_id, v.value, v.value_int, v.variant_id, f.feature_type, fd.description, fd.prefix,  | 0.000    |
| 14077 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 2    | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT pf.feature_id, pf.company_id, pf.feature_type, pf.parent_id, pf.display_on_product, pf.displa | 0.000    |
| 14095 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 109  | Sending data                 | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14107 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 103  | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14116 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 96   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14139 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 76   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14142 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 2    | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT pf.feature_id, pf.company_id, pf.feature_type, pf.parent_id, pf.display_on_product, pf.displa | 0.000    |
| 14149 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 69   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14154 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 66   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14169 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 52   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14175 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 49   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14178 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 47   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14186 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 2    | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT pf.feature_id, pf.company_id, pf.feature_type, pf.parent_id, pf.display_on_product, pf.displa | 0.000    |
| 14196 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 33   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14212 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Sleep   | 1    |                              |                                                                                                      | 0.000    |
| 14217 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 2    | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT pf.feature_id, pf.company_id, pf.feature_type, pf.parent_id, pf.display_on_product, pf.displa | 0.000    |
| 14222 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 11   | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS products.*, descr1.product as product, MIN(IF(prices.percentage_discount  | 0.000    |
| 14229 | kitxenon_autolux | localhost | kitxenon_bk | Query   | 2    | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT cscart_product_features_values.feature_id, COUNT(DISTINCT cscart_products.product_id) as prod | 0.000    |
| 14240 | root             | localhost |             | Query   | 0    | init                         | show processlist                                                                                     | 0.000    |
+-------+------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: If you have a question, you should review the Stack Overflow FAQ on asking questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to upgrade up to 4.3.3 version? CS-Cart team made a good work to optimize filters and decrease the website loading speed. Filters were bottle neck of this software before 4.3.1 version.

Comment: Actually, my theme and my other customized stuff are not compatible with 4.3, BUT, ive spent a couple hours and moved all the functions from 4.3 to 4.2 and changed the database structure and it all works now.